# What does $S^1$ do in many branches of math?

Tags: circles, big-list, group-isomorphism, spheres

There are many isomorphisms of $S^1$: $\hat{\Bbb Z}, \Bbb R/\Bbb Z, U(1),  SO(2), SL(1,\Bbb C), \Bbb T^1, \Bbb R\cup \{\infty\},\Bbb R\Bbb P^1  $. Seeing its importance, I'd like to see a synthesis of the roles of $S^1$ in each branch of math behind the isomorphisms. One can start with something like "as an isomorphism with $X$", "$X$ is the only $Y$ with property $z$" and then pursuit the ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a short list off the top of my head in no particular order:

1. It is a [dualizing object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizing+object) for locally compact abelian groups ([Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality)), establishing a contravariant autoequivalence $\text{Hom}(-, S^1)$ that restricts to various other well-known contravariant equivalences, e.g. between discrete and compact abelian groups, and between torsion and profinite abelian groups.
2. In algebraic topology, maps out of $S^1$ describe the [fundamental group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group) $\pi_1(-)$.
3. Also in algebraic topology, maps into $S^1$ describe the [cohomology group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology) $H^1(-, \mathbb{Z})$.
4. In Lie theory, $S^1$ is the simplest compact Lie group (say, connected, and with positive dimension); finite products of copies of $S^1$ describe [maximal tori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_torus) in compact Lie groups.
5. In harmonic analysis, studying its $L^2$ space gives rise to [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) of periodic functions (this is also an aspect of Pontryagin duality although very different from the aspect described in 1).